# Calculate max digits of percision on a floating point number

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy

According to wikipedia a single-percision floating point number maintains percision as long as there's less than 7 significant digits. Is there a formula for finding this maximum number of significant digits?

For example:
About how many decimal digits of precision does a floating-point format with a sign bit, 7-bit, excess 63 exponent, 8-bit fraction, and radix 2 exponentiation have?

Answer (score 0):

The number of decimal significant digits, inasmuch as this means anything, is more or less n/log<sub>2</sub>(10), where n is the number of significant binary digits. In your example the number of significant binary digits is 9 (implicit one followed by 8 significand bits). log<sub>2</sub>(10) is about 3.32, so you get slightly less than 3 significant decimal digits.

If you have a specific definition of “significant decimal digits” in mind, such as “the number of digits that can be round-triped through the binary format starting from a decimal representation with significant n digits and rounding to n decimal digits on the way back, without loss of information”, you will want to read [this Exploring Binary post](http://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-precision-of-binary-floating-point-numbers/).